# How to get intersection of the arrays in a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have an array like the following which is computed from another function I don't want to modify.

```
var d = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]];
```

I want to use `_.intersection` with all the arrays within the above array like this:

```
var c = _.intersection(d);
// should return [3]
```

but `_.intersection` takes multiple array parameters as input, not an array of arrays.

I have tried to flatten an array using something similar to [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript) but it convert the whole array into a single array.

```
var merged = [].concat.apply([], d);    
[1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3]; // I don't want this
```

Let me explain this in detail. I have a nested array `d` (which contains arrays and length is dynamic). Now I want to find the intersection of all arrays that are within array `d`.

**How can I call `_.intersection([1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3], ...)` but dynamically with `d`?**

Comment: Your desired result isn't a data structure. It's 3 separate values. If you want to extract each value individually, there's nothing stopping you from doing that. How do you intend to interact with that data after you've "flattened" it?

Comment: you cant set  `d = [1,2,3], [2,3], [1,3]` .  Please update your question to clearify what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: @Rooster updated

Comment: @RakeshSoni In response to your edit: so you want a function to return 3 values? It can't; it can only return one value. Again, how would you even interact with those 3 values? Pretend you've got the data in the format you want. Show us how you would use it.

Comment: @RakeshSoni ^    The answers posted might be what you want, but its still unclear what it is youre trying to do.

Comment: Updated the question again

Comment: @RakeshSoni You still haven't answered my question. Give an example of you using the data. If you want an ordered list of some kind of data, you need an array. If you want to access individual items, you just use normal array indexing. What you appear to be describing does not and cannot exist since you wouldn't have a way of referencing the data.

Comment: Can you include the expected result (valid JavaScript please)? Also, what does an intersection have to do with this?

Comment: Updated in detail, hope you all will understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES5 you can use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to spread the array into parameters:

```js
var d = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]];

var result = _.intersection.apply(_, d);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

You can use lodash's [`_.spread`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#spread) that will convert a function to consume an array of parameters:

```js
var d = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]];

var result = _.spread(_.intersection)(d);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In ES6 you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to do the same thing:

```js
const d = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]];

const result = _.intersection(...d);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome :) What method have you used?

Comment: `var result = _.intersection.apply(_, d);` this one, but i will also try other too :)

Comment: While the answer is valid for both, this question is tagged Underscore but isn't tagged LoDash as well. The first example should probably use Underscore.

Comment: @EmileBergeron - I went with your suggestion, and update the 1st and 3rd examples to underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Your desired result is not a data structure js would support. However, you can destructure the arrays into variables:

```js
let [a,b,c] = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]];
console.log(a,b,c);
```

The only valid representation of what you want to get is a string. You can get the exact result you've asked for like that :-) :

```js
let d = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [2, 3],
  [1, 3]
];

function createString(arr) {
  let s = arr.map(el => `[${el}]`).join(", ");
  return `result ${s};`;
}

console.log(createString(d));
```

Comment: but the length of the nested is dynamic, so this solution is not feasible

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do that is to put each of those internal arrays into a separate variable. With ES6, it's as easy as:

```
let d = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3], [1, 3]];
let [arr1, arr2, arr3] = d;
// -> arr1: [1, 2, 3], arr2: [2, 3], arr3: [1, 3]
```

Otherwise, you can do it using the standard ES5 syntax of course.

The only way you'll be able to work with all of those internal arrays with the same variable is to use the parent array you already have, `d`.